# sqlplus query doesn`t affects on database when run from crontab

Tags: bash, oracle, cron, sqlplus

I need to run some queries in crontab and they will be executed automatically at certain times.

I wrote a bash script for execute queries and some queries.

**executeQuery.sh** (file):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$ORACLE_HOME"
export PATH="$ORACLE_HOME:$PATH"

if ! command -v sqlplus > /dev/null ; then
        echo "This script requires sqlplus to be >installed and on your PATH. Exiting"
        exit 1
fi
if [  -z $1 -a  $1 = " " ]; then
        echo "query is empty"
        exit 1
fi

set -o allexport
source /home/oracle/scripts/.env
set +o allexport

sql="$(<"$1")"

echo "${sql}" | sqlplus -s   "${ORACLE_USERNAME}/${ORACLE_PASSWORD}@${ORACLE_HOST}:${ORACLE_PORT}/${ORACLE_SID}"
```

**testQuery.sql**(file):

```
update sample_database.sample_table sample_fields_1=0, sample_fields_2=0;
commit;
```

when run `bash executeQuery.sh  testQuery.sql` It works properly and show me:

> 32 rows updated.
>
> Commit complete.

but when run this script from crontab. This is not working :(

my **crontab**:

```
30 09 * * * /home/oracle/scripts/executeQuery.sh /home/oracle/scripts/testQuery.sql >> /home/oracle/scripts/log.log 2>&1
```

The result I get in the log file

> 32 rows updated.
>
> Commit complete

***Exactly the same output as when run script manually execution. But no any record has been updated in the database***

And I have to manually run the script again to get it applied correctly to the database

I have given full access (`777`) to the all files

Comment: You'll need to specify the full path to `testQuery.sql` in the crontab entry

Comment: Thank you for your attention. This mistake occurred in copying

Comment: correctly : 30 09 * * * /home/oracle/scripts/executeQuery.sh /home/oracle/scripts/testQuery.sql >> /home/oracle/scripts/log.log 2>&1

Comment: As which user you are running this script normally?

Comment: It might be useful to (temporarily!) have the script output exactly what it's running, so you can verify all the environment variables are as expected in both calls. The `.env` might not be doing exactly what you think - for instance, it might not change variables if they're already set, or reset them from some other file the cron version can't see. (Particularly if you run it manually or via cron as a different user - but that would suggest you've reduced the security on the `oracle` user's home directory, which doesn't seem like a good idea.)

Comment: run script from oracle user and set this script into crontab off oracle meanwhile chmod set 777 for all

Comment: In terms of security, a new user is assigned to this script in the database, which only has limited access
Of course, I used the main user for the test to make sure that there is no limitation from the Oracle side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For connecting Oracle database through crontab it might be good to switch to `oracle` user.

Try this:

```
30 09 * * * su - oracle -c "/home/oracle/scripts/executeQuery.sh /home/oracle/scripts/testQuery.sql >> /home/oracle/scripts/log.log 2>&1"
```

Comment: I thought that each user's crontab is the same as the one who executes it, but apparently it is not so

Answer (score 0):

You miss a lot of Oracle RDBMS specific variables in your script. When you use terminal they are (probably) set, but not in cron. So add something like in you bash script (on the second line for example.

```
source /home/oracle/.bashrc
```

this will add all the settings you get when login in to the machine.